# Finding the divisor and quotient of long n

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write an algorithm for a program that finds the factors for the sum of all numbers in the range of long n.

I've got a working version below but how do I store the divisor and quotient (i and sumValue%i)into the long array.
PS: The sum function calculates the sum of all numbers in the range of long n.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class RemovedNumbers {
  
    public static List<long[]> removNb(long n) {
    
    long[] factors;
    long sumValue = Sum(n);
    
    for(long i=0;i<=n;i++){
      if(sumValue%i == 0){
        factors = new(i, sumValue%i);
        return factors;
      }
    }
    
        // your code
        return null;
    }
  
  public static long Sum(long n){
     return n(n+1)/2; 
    }
}
```

@Flydog57 I edited the code but my soultion for is not correct It fails when tested it returns null all the time.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class RemovedNumbers {
   
    public static List<long[]> removNb(long n) {
    if (n>0){
      RemovedNumbers.Finder(n);
    }
         
    return null;
  }
  
//This function calculates the sum of all the numbers in a given n  
public static long Sum(long n){
      long sum = 0, x;
       for (x = 1; x <= n; x++){
        sum += x;
       }
    return sum;
    }
  
//This function finds x and y for x*y = Sum(n)-(x+y)  
public static List<long[]> Finder(long n){
    
    var sum = Sum(n); 
    List<long[]> factors = new List<long[]>();
    
        for(long x=0;x<=n;x++){
          for(long y=0;y<=n;y++){
            if ((x*y)+x+y == sum){
            factors.Add(new long[] {x, y});
            }
          }
        }
  return factors;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your input and expected result?

Comment: Do you want to have a `List<_divisor and quotient_>` as your result?  Create a class (maybe even a struct) with two simple auto-properties, both `long` named `Divisor` and `Quotient`.  Create instances of that type, properly initialized, and add them to your `List<WhateverThatTypeIs>`.  Does your code compile?  This doesn't look right: `factors = new(i, sumValue%i);`

Comment: @Flydog57 how do I create instances of that type? when I tried using the new keyword. I get the following error CS1526: A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type

Comment: I can't tell what you are trying to do. Your function is declared to return a `List<long[]>`, but it appears you are trying to return a 2-tuple of longs. If I understood what you were trying to do, it would be pretty easy.

Comment: @Flydog57 I'm trying to solve this kata on Codewars https://www.codewars.com/kata/5547cc7dcad755e480000004/train/csharp

Comment: You know you can edit your question and put formatted code in there, right?

Comment: @Flydog57 I just figured that out. Thanks for the tip. And my code will make more sense once you look at the problem on codewars :)